# How to implement pointers into a game I am creating for school

Tags: c, pointers

I am creating a game for my computer class. I am supposed to create a 50x50 array that a user can use 'w' 'a' 's' 'd' to move though the maze. However, my teacher told me I need to go back and implement pointers into the program to receive full credit. What are some ways I can use pointers in my program and can you please explain how because I don't understand pointers all that much.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printMaze(char MAZE[50][50]);

int main(void)
{
  int yValue = 9;
  int xValue = 0;
  int escapeXvalue = 49;
  int escapeYvalue = 9;
  int escapeYvalue2 = 39;
  char movement;

  //50 x 50 array MAZE using '*' to represent walls and ' ' to represent a moveable path
  char MAZE[50][50] =
  {
    {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'},
    {'*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'0',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' '},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ',' '},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*'},
    {'*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*'},
    {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'}};

    //infinite loop only untill logic for figuring out how MAZE logic should work
    //loop iterates through user choices for movement through the MAZE
    while(1){
      if ((yValue == escapeYvalue && xValue == escapeXvalue) || (yValue == escapeYvalue2 && xValue == escapeXvalue))
      {
    system("clear");
    printf("You beat the game! \n");
    return 0;
      }
      printMaze(MAZE);
      printf("Enter direction you want to move A(left) S(down) D(right) W(up)\n");
      movement = getchar();
      /*
      the 'if' statements in the cases represent checks to make sure the move
      doesn't conflict with out of bounds in the array or traversal through a '*'
      */
      switch(movement){
        case 'A' :
        case 'a' :
        //player is moving character to the left
          if(xValue > 0 && MAZE[yValue][xValue - 1] == ' '){
              printf("A action executed\n");
              MAZE[yValue][xValue] = ' ';
              xValue --;
              MAZE[yValue][xValue] = '0';
          }
          else{
            printf("A action could not be executed\n");
          }
          system("clear");
          break;


        case 'D' :
        case 'd' :
        //player is moving character to the right
          if(xValue < 50 && MAZE[yValue][xValue + 1] == ' '){
              printf("D action executed\n");
              MAZE[yValue][xValue] = ' ';
              xValue ++;
              MAZE[yValue][xValue] = '0';
          }
          else{
            printf("D action could not be preformed\n");
          }
          system("clear");
          break;



        case 'S' :
        case 's' :
        //player is moving character down
          if(yValue < 50 && MAZE[yValue + 1][xValue] == ' '){
            printf("S action executed\n");
            MAZE[yValue][xValue] = ' ';
            yValue ++;
            MAZE[yValue][xValue] = '0';

          }
          else{
            printf("S action could not be executed\n");
          }
          system("clear");
          break;

        case 'W' :
        case 'w' :
        //player is moving character up
          if(yValue > 0 && MAZE[yValue - 1][xValue] == ' '){
              printf("W action executed\n");
              MAZE[yValue][xValue] = ' ';
              yValue --;
              MAZE[yValue][xValue] = '0';
          }
          else{
              printf("W action could not be preformed\n");
          }
          system("clear");
          break;
      }
    }
}

void printMaze(char MAZE[][50])
{
  for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
  {
    for(int y = 0; y < 50; y++)
    {
      printf("%c ", MAZE[x][y]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read some basic information about pointers here, for example: https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-pointers/

Pointers are, basically, just variables which store the address of another variable in memory. You can imagine them in some sense like an arrow which is pointing to another place in the memory. Imagine if memory was a map. Lets say you do:

```
House myHouse;
```

and allocate space in that map for a house, your house, you can imagine you received the place your house is indeed occupying in the world. Then, if you made a pointer to your house like

```
House* pointer;
pointer = &myHouse;
```

the pointer would be like a paper where you have your address written (notice the & is used to get the address).
Since you specify the type of data saved in the pointed direction when you create the pointer (you put int*, for example, to tell the compiler "this pointer points to a place in memory which saves integers"), the compiler is able to allow you to do some operations with them.
In the case of an array, as it is the case in your program, you can move pointers along an array by adding or substracting integers.
If we have the pointer to your house we defined previously, and your house is the first element of an array of houses, then the operation "pointer + 1" will return the address of the next house in the array.

So I assume your teacher expects you to use a pointer to save the current position of the player, and to use this integer sum cleverly to make the movement.

PS: there is a lot of repetition in your code, which usually is a bad practice, consider dividing it into some functions more, like one to check if a place is empty and one to move given a specific direction, for example.